# Function satisfying both these limits

Tags: limits, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

What is an example of a function $f(x)$ that satisfies both

$\lim_{x\rightarrow0} f(x)/x^2 = C$, any finite non-zero real number

and

$\lim_{x\rightarrow0} f(x)/x = 1$?

I'm struggling to find anything that works after trying lots of different functions.

Comment: By limit laws your first condition implies that $f(x) /x=(f(x) /x^2)x\to C\cdot 0=0$ and hence the second condition is not satisfied. You don't need any restriction on $C$ like being non-zero. Always use limit laws to get rid of obvious doubts.

Answer (score 1):

this is not possible, you can check that by dividing the second limit by the first one, and you get :

$$\lim_{x\to0}x=\frac{1}{C}=0 $$

Which is not possible

Comment: clever, well done!!!

Comment: "this is not possible except for $c=0.$"  What do you mean?

Comment: well, I got confused for a moment when dividing the 2 expression, indeed it doesn't work with $C=0$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\ \lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{f(x)}{x}\right) = 1$.

Then given $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{10},\ \exists\ \delta\ $ with $\ 0<\delta<\frac{1}{10}$ such that $\left|1-\frac{f(x)}{x}\right| < \frac{1}{10} \quad \forall\ |x|<\delta.\ $ So we have,

$\frac{9}{10} < \frac{f(x)}{x} < \frac{11}{10}$ and $0<|x|<\frac{1}{10},\ $ which implies $\ \large{\left| \frac{\frac{f(x)}{x}}{x} \right| } >\ $$9\quad \forall\ |x|<\delta.$

Now we may rewrite all of the above by replacing $10$ with any *real* number $r >1$.

Given $\varepsilon_r=\frac{1}{r}\ (r>1),\ \exists\ \delta_r\ $ with $\ 0<\delta_r<\frac{1}{r}$ such that $\left|1-\frac{f(x)}{x}\right| < \frac{1}{r} \quad \forall\ |x|<\delta_r.\ $ Since $r>1,$ we have:

$0<\frac{r-1}{r} < \frac{f(x)}{x} < \frac{r+1}{r}$ and $0<|x|<\frac{1}{r},\ $ which implies $\ \large{\left| \frac{\frac{f(x)}{x}}{x} \right| } >\ $$r-1\quad \forall\ |x|<\delta_r.$

This is almost the definition of $\lim_{x \to 0}\large{\left| \frac{\frac{f(x)}{x}}{x} \right| } = \infty,$ which tells us, among other things, that $\large{\left| \frac{\frac{f(x)}{x}}{x} \right| }$ does not converge as $x \to 0$.